# Algorithm for kerning divs

Tags: javascript, html

Before suggesting bin packing algorithms, they assume you can re-order the elements and arrange them any way you please.  Note as you read that I have a restriction on the ordering and arrangement.

So obviously there's no such thing as kerning divs, but it's the most appropriate term I could think of.  Basically I have a lot of elements on a page, divs and imgs, with fixed width and height.  They have to remain in order (they are chronological) and should be displayed left to right, top to bottom.  I want to "kern" the elements in such a way as to make the whitespace as uniform as possible.  It's a very easy task to achieve horizontally, but vertical whitespace is more difficult.  Uneven excess whitespace around the outermost edge of the packed elements is acceptable.

I was thinking as a really dumb solution, I could set the max width of the area to be packed to something like 1000px.  Then I could keep an array with 1000 indices keeping track of the bottom of that column of pixels on the screen.  When I add a new element, I see if it should be moved up a little into a gap and if shifting it left or right a little bit would allow it to be moved up.

As I said, that's a really dumb solution.  Are there any algorithms I could use or has anyone had to deal with a similar packing problem?

**UPDATE:**

Per questions in comments.  The elements have random widths and heights.  My test case is to create 100 image tags with images from placekitten.com with random widths and heights in the 200-300px range and arrange those images on the page in the order they are generated.

Create an html page and throw the below code in your head to get to where I am (please no comments on general code quality, I know there are some optimizations, I literally threw this together as a demo in under 10 minutes):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var maxwidth = window.innerWidth - 80;
    function justify(row, filled)
    {
        var remaining = maxwidth - filled + 30,
            imgs = $('img',row),
            margin = Math.floor((remaining/imgs.length) / 2);
        $(imgs).each(function(){ this.style.marginLeft=margin+"px";this.style.marginRight=margin+"px"});
    }

    $(function()
    {
        var row = document.createElement('div'),
            filled = 0;
        document.body.appendChild(row);
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            var img = document.createElement('img'),
                width = Math.floor(200 + Math.random() * 100),
                height = Math.floor(200 + Math.random() * 100);
            if ((filled + width) > maxwidth)
            {
                justify(row, filled);
                row = document.createElement('div');
                filled = 0;
                document.body.appendChild(row);
            }
            filled += width;
            img.src = "http://placekitten.com/" + width + "/" + height;
            row.appendChild(img);
        }
        justify(row,filled);
    })
</script>
<style>
    img{position:relative; vertical-align:middle}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried jquery plugins to fix the height of them or take the height in jQuery of 'n' many elements at a time and then standardise the elements from the beginning of the row to the end and repeat per row? or anything like that? what have you tried?

Comment: @MyStream I haven't tried dealing with vertical height, but I can justify elements nicely across horizontal rows.  The difficult bit is vertical spacing.  Making the elements all the same size defeats the whole point of this problem and doesn't look as interesting on the page.

Comment: Are the elements of varying width? Or is it more like columns of varying height?  A screenshot of what it looks like now and what you'd like it to look like after might make your problem easier to understand.

Comment: @Alex Height and width both random within limits.  At the moment I'm pulling 100 images from placekitten between 200px and 300px in both dimensions (not square, width and height generated separately with `200 + Math.random()*100`) and arranging them on the page.  As I've said, Arranging horizontally is easy, it's the vertical bit that's difficult.  I'll see about putting together some screens later but I'd have to photoshop the desired look and I suck at PS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the beautiful [Masonry Plugin](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry) I used for a similar problem.

Also, try similar plugins like [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) and [jLayout](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jlayout/jquery-plugin.html).

Good luck.

Comment: Cheers! Masonry looks pretty awesome, will definitely give it a whirl and report back.

Comment: Masonry made a good attempt so I'm accepting this answer, however, I've decided to use a solution where I create a number of templates of a fixed height and width with different internal layouts and I fit my content into that layout.  That produces a much cleaner, better filled page. Masonry left a lot of big gaps when there was significant variance in the size of items.